# Submitting two different forms from a single submit button in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to submit two different forms dat,a each having a submit button, in two different tables in the same database after clicking on the second form's submit button using PHP?

Comment: and the question is on php programming in general... i see... mmm... can't help you with that. maybe insert $CODEZ into 'database'

Comment: PHP runs on the server side. It doesn't submit forms, unless you're trying to doing the actual form submits programatically from PHP. Please make your question clearer, with an example, and show what you have tried so for.

Answer (score 2):

Create the a number of hidden fields in the second form (depending on how many textfields you have in the first one). On the second submit buttone use `onclick="return xxx()"` where xxx is a function that sets the hidden fields in the second form with the values from the first one. Just remember to return `bool` from xxx().

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server side and (usually) renders HTML before the user has a chance to interact with it. You can't, as far as I know, connect a single button to two forms with only HTML, hence you can't do it with only PHP. You'll have to use JavaScript, for instance you could use jQuery to intercept the submit event and do whatever you want to do instead of letting the form submit a request as usual.